# How to create loading screen with angular-cli

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, loader

I have an angular2 project created with angular-cli. Angular-cli use webpack.

I would custom the loader, because the "Loading..." in black on white background is not ok for me.

So, I rewrite the index.html with an svg animation for the loader. But the animation is lagged and sometimes freezed. My first solution, remove the *.bundle.js at the end of the index.html. Then, I catch the DOMContentLoaded event to show the svg. Bingo, is very neat.

And then, I add dynamically differents scripts *.bundle.js for webpack.

The problem is in the main.bundle.js because there is an error during the execution.

If I let the raw scripts in the DOM it works but not dynamically.

So, instead of:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

I put:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var app = document.getElementsByTagName("app-root")[0];
    body.removeChild(app);

    function appendScript(src){
      var s = document.createElement("script");
      s.src = src;
      s.type = "text/javascript";
      body.appendChild(s);
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      var timer = setInterval(function(){
        body.appendChild(app);

        appendScript("inline.bundle.js");
        appendScript("polyfills.bundle.js");
        appendScript("scripts.bundle.js");
        appendScript("styles.bundle.js");
        appendScript("vendor.bundle.js");
        appendScript("main.bundle.js");
        clearInterval(timer);
      }, 1500);
    })
  </script>
```

I want to show the loader before the loading of different bundles..

I remove the app-root because I wish have a css animation on opacity to have fade effect

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap c9cc4a4…:52)
    at Object.192 (src async:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap c9cc4a4…:52)
    at Object.635 (main.bundle.js:4838)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap c9cc4a4…:52)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap c9cc4a4…:23)
    at main.bundle.js:1
```

I added a console.log into __webpack__require function to show the moduleId which broke the execution. This moduleId is 1

Have you some ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible solutions:
If you want to have static animation just put this animation in your index.html
inside the app tag

```
<app-root>
    <div id="preloader">
      <div class="sk-wave">
          <div class="sk-rect sk-rect1"></div>
          <div class="sk-rect sk-rect2"></div>
          <div class="sk-rect sk-rect3"></div>
          <div class="sk-rect sk-rect4"></div>
          <div class="sk-rect sk-rect5"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</app-root>
```

I have css style making animation for the `preloader` element, but this is not relevant. The important part is that you application will overwrite this loader after application load all content of the `app-root` element.

=======================================================================
Second option... This time you don't put it inside of the `app-root` element.

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <div id="preloader">
      <div class="sk-wave">
          <div class="sk-rect sk-rect1"></div>
          <div class="sk-rect sk-rect2"></div>
          <div class="sk-rect sk-rect3"></div>
          <div class="sk-rect sk-rect4"></div>
          <div class="sk-rect sk-rect5"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body
```

Then you use [Angular2 Lifecicle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) to hide the preloader after view

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloaderService } from './_ui-module/_preloader';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.styl' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private preloader: PreloaderService){

    }

    //HERE
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.preloader.hide();
    }

}
```

Comment: I use the first solution, but I want to show the loader before the loading of different bundles..

Answer (score 0):

Find a pure css loading page and put the `<div>` element inside the `app-root`. these are really cool ones by lukehaas:  https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/

here is a working sample I did using one of the spinners from the link above: https://plnkr.co/edit/J3JNhm82Rgxq1h9h9ktb?p=preview

Here are the changes I made:

1. inside `body` I added a `<style>` tag, copied one of the styles in link above from source and added it inside `<style>`
2. Add the source html, again from the source on lukehaas's site. add that inside the root element `my-app` like so: (it's `<app-root>` in your case).

   ```
   <my-app>
         <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
   </my-app>
   ```

once angular has bootstrapped, it will remove everything inside  and the loader will be gone.

Comment: I use the first solution, but I want to show the loader before the loading of different bundles..

Comment: if you do it according to my answer, they are all in-line so it'll always be the first thing to show up. Look at the plunkr link. It works as expected. it's more dependable and predictable than using angular to do it. If angular has errors or does not load, this will still work.

Comment: My loader works correctly but if I use a slow connection, the animation is lagged or sometimes freezed. So, if I load in two times the page, svg firstly and scripts secondly, this problem is resolved. But, webpack can't load the moduleId=1

If I keep script in raw html into my index.html, webpack works correctly but not the animation with poor network :/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. And it works very

I fixed my appendScript function.

```
function appendScript(src){
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = src;
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.async = false;
  body.appendChild(s);
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

"[1] In older browsers that don't support the async attribute, parser-inserted scripts block the parser; script-inserted scripts execute asynchronously in IE and WebKit, but synchronously in Opera and pre-4.0 Firefox. In Firefox 4.0, the async DOM property defaults to true for script-created scripts, so the default behavior matches the behavior of IE and WebKit. To request script-inserted external scripts be executed in the insertion order in browsers where the document.createElement("script").async evaluates to true (such as Firefox 4.0), set .async=false on the scripts you want to maintain order. Never call document.write() from an async script. In Gecko 1.9.2, calling document.write() has an unpredictable effect. In Gecko 2.0, calling document.write() from an async script has no effect (other than printing a warning to the error console).

[2] Starting in Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4 / Thunderbird 3.3 / SeaMonkey 2.1), inserting script elements that have been created by calling document.createElement("script") into the DOM no longer enforces execution in insertion order. This change lets Gecko properly abide by the HTML5 specification. To make script-inserted external scripts execute in their insertion order, set .async=false on them."